# What are the impacts of running VirusScan on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, anti-virus

I am asked in a bid for tender to assert that my software will cohabit without a problem with **VirusScan** (v6.0.3) under **Linux**.

My software is a web application, running under tomcat.
It can create additional JVMs (to run ETL jobs) and writes reporting files (mostly PDF and HTML) in an application directory.

Are there any specific problem I should be aware of regarding VirusScan running on the server my app will run on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impacts of running AV on linux are the same as the impacts of running AV on any other OS. A couple of the main impacts that come to mind are:

1. Increased IO, CPU, and Memory load
2. Possibility of bad things happening due to false positives

Point #1 can be mitigated by scaling hardware properly, and #2 can be mitigated via AV software configuration such as exempting certain critical files, but of course then you run the risk of those exempted files getting infected without detection.

Comment: Are file locking problems possible, or is this handled in a proper manner ?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be, except in the case of a virus detection and subsequent deletion/quarantine of course.